# Reading a file and doing math

Tags: python, list, loops, file, text

I've been working on this for some time. I made a small step of progress, but am stuck.

The txt file contains float values that look like this, as an example:

```
2921.492649999950 5520.499056604050 2670.121720935130 -3.54035405410219 4.39482975106974 -5.18433931744563
1975.765991528470 6361.404021360910 1343.558197474950 -4.29247850018471 2.56997398564163 -5.80254821596864
```

What my code **should** do is read the first three numbers on a line, square them, then add them, and then do the same for the next three numbers on that same line.

**Example:** First line has:  a b -c, d, -e, -f
=> a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = variable 1

=> d^2 + e^2 + f^2 = variable 2

Then repeat for the next line, and then for every line in the file.

I'm trying to do this for a very simple case, because I have a hard time understanding how to handle reading and manipulating data from a file. I get lost with the int, floats, str, and the errors messages, etc.

What my program is doing is reading each of the (float) numbers digit-by-digit and not the entire decimal number as I want it to, and need some help, please.

I need to keep all the decimal places on the numbers.

Thanks

```
fp = open('ISS TEST Numbers.txt', "r")

line = fp.readline()
print( float(line[0])**2)
n = 0
while n <= len(line):
    print(len(line))
    cnt = 1

    print( float(line[0])**2 + float(line[1])**2 + float(line[2])**2 )
    print(float(line[6]) ** 2 + float(line[8]) ** 2 + float(line[10]) ** 2)

    while line:
        print(line.strip())
        line = fp.readline()

        cnt += 1
        n = n + 1
fp.close()
```

Comment: You need to `split` the line on space and map each to `float`. Ex: `map(float, line.split(' '))`

Comment: Or use list comprehension: `[float(f) for f in lines.split(' ')]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open and read the file with

```
with open('ISS TEST Numbers.txt', "r") as in_file : text_numbers = in_file.read()
```

then you extract the numbers from the string, creating a list of numbers for each line

```
num_by_line = [[float(num) for num in line.split()] 
                for line in text_numbers.split("\n")]
```

and finally you can iterate over each list, summing up the squares

```
variables = [[sum(list_num[3*y+x]**2 for x in range(3)) 
              for y in range(len(list_num)//3)]
              for list_num in num_by_line]
```

printing `variables` with the example file we obtain

```
[[46140579.14257951, 58.72600952769815], [46176261.00626936, 58.69970376006354]]
```

Comment: This is great, I was way off in how I was thinking about this. I'll have to study the construct so I really understand how it's working. If I plotted each 'x' & 'y' this would have to be done within the "variables" loop, correct? Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! For 'x' and 'y' do you mean the ones inside `variables` in my code? or something else? like the result of the sum of squares as 'y' and something else for 'x'

Comment: for the first one you can rewrite  `variables` as `[[[(x,y,f"in_list_index: {3*y+x}") for x in range(3)] for y in range(len(list_num)//3)] for list_num in num_by_line]` to understand the construct better

Comment: Anyway it works like this: the rightmost for loop take each list for each line one by one, the second one divides the len of the list by three so that to find the number of the variables to create for that line, then the last for loop creates each three by three sum for that list.

Comment: the 'x' & 'y', yes, I will need to plot them. Thanks **again**. I have a lot to read over with with the code you've given. I will go over it thoroughly so I understand what's happening. I've been working on this whole project for some weeks. Get stuck a lot and it gets frustrating, but you really helped!